# Why does this command not work on AIX?

Tags: sed, ksh, aix

I want to remove UTF-8 BOM from a file using this command:

```
sed '1 s/\xEF\xBB\xBF//' old.java > tmp.java
```

But it did not work. 
I am running with ksh on AIX 7.1

Comment: I don't know about AIX, but most `sed` implementations don't interpret `\x` sequences, so your command is probably replacing litteral "backslash x E F ..." sequences. You'll have to include litteral binary characters in your sed command, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIX sed does not understand escape sequence characters, as the [AIX sed document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/manip_strings_sed.htm%23a3149514?cp=ssw_aix_53&lang=en) said, it only know ASCII characters. So you should use another tools.

**tail**

```
tail -c +4 old.java > tmp.java
```

**awk**

```
awk '{NR==1{sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"")}1' old.java > tmp.java
```

Answer (score 3):

In POSIX, the behaviour is unspecified for `\x` in a basic regexp. Some implementations use it to introduce hex byte representations, some (like yours) treat it like `x`.

POSIXly, you could do:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
 sed "s/$(printf '\357\273\277')//") < file.in > file.out
```

Here, you may also have some luck with:

```
< file.in iconv -t UTF-16LE | iconv -f UTF-16 > file.out
```

I can't say if that would work in AIX, but with GNU `iconv`, `UTF-16` means UTF-16 with BOM, while UTF-16LE means UTF-16 little endian, so the second `iconv` would strip the UTF-16LE BOM produced by the first (would also work with UTF-16BE).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Needed to remove BOM (UTF-16LE) from a file. Ended up using "tr" with octal codes for the 0xFF 0xFE:

```
$ cat old.csv
ÿþ"SET01"|"0000001"|"2016-11-15"|""|"0"|""|""|"Data01"

$ echo "ibase=16\nobae=8\nFF" | bc
377
$ echo "ibase=16\nobae=8\nFE" | bc
376

$ cat old.csv | tr -d "\377\376"
"SET01"|"0000001"|"2016-11-15"|""|"0"|""|""|"Data01"
```

Comment: `tr -d '\377\376'` would remove all the occurrences of all the `\377` and `\376` bytes. Fine only as long as the file otherwise only contains ASCII characters. (you'll probably want to remove the NUL bytes as well if that's UTF-16 indeed). Here, if that's UTF-16, I would do `iconv -f UTF-16` instead.

Answer (score 0):

still cannot comment - so if you would like to try using GNU iconv - as a more robust solution, without killing the programs that depend on AIX iconv I may have a package that will work for you.

```
michael@x071:[/home/michael]ar -X64 tv /usr/lib/libiconv.a
rwxr-xr-x     0/0     1032868 Aug 21 16:19 2016 libiconv.so.2
r--r--r--     0/0     159410 Aug 21 20:09 2016 shr4_64.o

michael@x071:[/home/michael]ar -X32 tv /usr/lib/libiconv.a
rwxr-xr-x     0/0     1010856 Aug 21 16:21 2016 libiconv.so.2
r--r--r--     0/0     117276 Aug 21 20:09 2016 shr4.o
r--r--r--     0/0     117526 Aug 21 20:09 2016 shr.o
```

(64-bit) Programs depending on AIX iconv will be looking for /usr/lib/libiconv.a(shr4_64.o) (32-bit look for /usr/lib/libiconv.a(shr4.o)) while those, such as GNU iconv look to /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)

```
michael@x071:[/home/michael]ldd /usr/bin/iconv
/usr/bin/iconv needs:
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libiconv.a(shr4.o)
         /unix
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)

michael@x071:[/home/michael]ldd /opt/bin/iconv
/opt/bin/iconv needs:
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)
         /unix
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
```

You can get GNU iconv for AIX via http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/libiconv and can be side-by-side with AIX iconv.